# How to set `filterset_fields` in Django-Filter and Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

When I set the fiterset_fields like below,

```py
class SubCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ["category_id"] # single underscore
```

I get this response when a category with the specified ID doesn't exist

```py
{
    "category_id": [
        "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
    ]
}
```

But when I set it like

```py
class SubCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ["category__id"] # notice the double underscore
```

I get a `[]` when a category with the specified ID doesn't exist.

Why does this happen?
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen? What is the right way to do this?

This is partly one of the limitations of Django. If you use a fieldname, like `category_id`, is one, it will first retrieve a collection if *distinct* values. If the entered value is not in it, then it can raise the exception.

If you work with JOINs, however, as is the case with `category__id`, where you join on an extra model, that trick apparently is not implemented. It might be possible to do this, although it can be tricky for multiple JOINs, especially if there is some other filtering active that filters on another JOIN that partly overlaps. So since Django in that case can not derive a unique set of values, it fallsback on returning an empty list.

I would advise to use the first one, so `category_id`. Indeed, if someone enters a wrong `category_id`, it is more informative to say that the `category_id` does not exist, and not return an empty list. In the latter case it gives the impression that the category exists, but that there is simply no subcategory with that category. Usually providing more information is better, of course if it is not "sensitive".

Answer (score 1):

Lets first see the difference between them.

### Case 1

You are defining a `category_id` field for filtering, and django is assuming that `category_id` is a field of Model. The viewset here expects the `category_id` field to be present in the request and to contain a valid choice from the available choices. Otherwise it will generate the error.

### Case 2

You are defining a `category__id` field for filtering, and django is assuming that Category Model has a field called `id` that will be used for filtering purposes. It filters results based on id attribute in Category model and if the result set is empty, it returns empty list as []. Note: this approach is recommended due to the flexibility it provides.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).